# Got an ORA-01788 error without using level or start with

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have just started to learn PL/SQL. Following a post in stackoverflow, I have written a script to search a certain value in Oracle as below:

```
DECLARE
  match_count INTEGER;
  v_owner VARCHAR2(255);
  v_search_value NUMBER;
BEGIN
  v_owner:='USERA USERB';
  v_search_value:=4823.0;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  'INSERT INTO TMP SELECT owner, table_name, column_name FROM all_tab_cols WHERE instr(:1, owner)>0 AND data_type like ''%NUMBER%''' USING v_owner;
  commit;
  FOR t IN (SELECT owner, table_name, column_name FROM TMP) LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '||t.owner||'.'||t.table_name||' WHERE '||t.column_name||'= :1'
    INTO match_count
    USING v_search_value;
    IF match_count > 0 THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'INSERT INTO RESULT VALUES(:1, :2, :3, :4)'
      USING t.owner, t.table_name, t.column_name, match_count;
      commit;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The table TMP and RESULT have been properly created before executing the script. However, when I run the script, I get an ORA-01788 error saying that "connect by clause required" on line 12. I wonder why the code cause this error and how to change the script to be executed properly. Thanks!

Comment: as t is the child node, you have to use connect  by show how to walk from parent node to child node.

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me how to change this script? Because I am a newbie in PL/SQL.

Comment: Why are you using `execute immediate` for `INSERTS` ?

Comment: Are you running this script in `SQLPLUS` ? Can you copy and paste the output of this script? And it would be easy for us to answer if you give us the structure of `TEMP` table with some sample rows.

Comment: I bet you have a column named 'level'.

Answer (score 6):

You probably have a table with a column called `level` (as Florin suggested while I wasn't looking), which is a [reserved word](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/ap_keywd001.htm).

It may be in any case - not just `level`, but `LEVEL`, or `Level` - so to check you could do:

```
select owner, table_name, column_name
from all_tab_columns
where upper(column_name) = 'LEVEL';
```

Or to look for any reserved words in use (though this won't always find all potential problems):

```
select atc.owner, atc.table_name, atc.column_name, vrw.keyword
from all_tab_columns atc
join v$reserved_words vrw on vrw.keyword = upper(atc.column_name);
```

You could run similar queries against `all_tables` or `all_objects` to find potential problems elsewhere.

If I run a modified version of your query which doesn't bother with the `TMP` table - not sure why you'd want that; doesn't use dynamic SQL for the inserts; doesn't commit (which is an odd thing to do in a block - you don't need to do it after every insert anyway); and just for my benefit just displays the matches instead of needing to build a `results` table:

```
declare
  match_count integer;
  v_owner varchar2(255);
  v_search_value number;
begin
  v_owner := 'USERA USERB';
  v_search_value := 4823.0;
  for t in (
      select owner, table_name, column_name
      from all_tab_cols
      where instr(v_owner, owner) > 0
      and data_type like '%NUMBER%'
    ) loop
    execute immediate 
      'select count(*) from ' || t.owner ||'.'|| t.table_name
        || ' where ' || t.column_name || ' = :1'
      into match_count using v_search_value;
    if match_count > 0 then
--    insert into results values (t.owner, t.table_name,
--      t.column_name, match_count);
      dbms_output.put_line('Matched ' || t.owner ||'.'|| t.table_name
        ||'.'|| t.column_name ||': '|| match_count);
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

... this completes successfully. If I add a table with a `level` column:

```
create table t42 ("LEVEL" number);
```

... and then run the same block again then I also get:

```
ORA-01788: CONNECT BY clause required in this query block
ORA-06512: at line 14
01788. 00000 -  "CONNECT BY clause required in this query block"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Aside from avoiding reserved words in object names, you can make this work by enclosing all of your object names in double-quotes:

```
    execute immediate 
      'select count(*) from "' || t.owner ||'"."'|| t.table_name
        || '" where "' || t.column_name || '" = :1'
      into match_count using v_search_value;
```

This will also cope with mixed-case object names, which you should also avoid.

Comment: Thank you Alex Poole. First I ran the script you modified but still got an ORA-01788 error, then I searched all the tables in USERA & USERB for a column whose name was like '%level%' according to Florin Ghita's advice, but found nothing. Finally I enclosed the object names in double-quotes and that worked! Thanks all of you for your advice. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @FrederichChen - Neither of us meant to imply that it would necessarily be lower-case, we just both seem to prefer coding like that since Oracle is (usually) case-insentive. I'll add the check I would do.